# TrackBy must be a function, but received undefined In angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a demo app in Angular 2. But while doing this, I got this error:

**core.umd.js:3491 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in security.component.html:35:72 caused by: trackBy must be a function, but received undefined.
Error: trackBy must be a function, but received undefined**

Anyone can suggest me what I am doing wrong in the below code?

**security.component.html:**

```
<h2>Template :</h2>
<template ngFor let-hero [ngForOf]="heroes" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" [ngForTrackBy]="trackById">
  <div [class.odd]="odd">({{i}}) {{hero.name}}</div>
</template>
```

**security.component.ts:**

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    moduleId    :     module.id,
    selector    :     'security-component',
    templateUrl :     '../views/security.component.html'
})

export class securityComponent{

    private heroes = [
    {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'     },
    {id: 12, name: 'Narco'        },
    {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'     },
    {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'    },
    {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'      },
    {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'    },
    {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'       },
    {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'        },
    {id: 19, name: 'Magma'        },
    {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'      }
      ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trackBy` takes a function which has two arguments: `index` and `item`. If `trackBy` is given, Angular tracks changes by the return value of the function.

So you need to have function with name `trackById` in your component

```
trackById(index, hero) {
  return hero.id    
}
```

Since 2.4.2 is allowed to use `null/undefined` values for `NgForTrackBy` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#242-2017-01-06

Answer (score 0):

SecurityComponent needs to define `trackById`

```
export class SecurityComponent {
  trackById({id}: Hero) {
    return id;
  }
}
```